# UITextField, hided Keyboard, TopBar still there

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

i have a VC with a UITextField. Thats my Code:

.h

```
@interface GameOverViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}
```

.m

```
@implementation UITextField (DisableCopyPaste)

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{

return NO;
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}

@end

@implementation GameOverViewController

NSString *text1;



text1 = @"";

UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_nameField.inputView = testView;
[_nameField becomeFirstResponder];
_nameField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

This is for hiding the Keyboard:

```
UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_nameField.inputView = testView;
```

But now there is still the TopBar of the Keyboard on my View:

[image: bottombar]

If i take out this two lines of code, the whole Keyboard appears:

[image]

i can't get it hided. i don't want this bar.

if i disable the UITextField, the Bar is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

in iOS 9 there is an UITextInoutAssistantItem, and here is my Solution for this Bar:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)]) {

UITextInputAssistantItem *item = [self inputAssistantItem];
item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
}
```